# Iterated functions

Tags: limits, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, fixed-point-theorems

A function F(x) when composed in itself number of times is called an iterated function.

Let $F(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$

$F(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{2}{3}$

$F(\frac{2}{3})=\frac{3}{5}$

$F(\frac{3}{5})=\frac{5}{8}$

Continuing in this way to infinite number of times it turns out that we get $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}.$

But we see above that we will continue to get rational fractions however long we continue.

So $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ or simply $\sqrt{5}$ is rational.

Are we incorrect in assumption or we haven't defined irrational numbers properly?

Comment: A limit of a sequence of rationals may be irrational.

Comment: Check out the limit of consecutive quotients here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of a sequence of rational numbers that approximate an irrational number closer and closer:

$$3,\\ 3.1, \\3.14, \\3.141, \\3.1415, \\3.14159, \\3.141592, \\3.1415926,\\\cdots$$

Such a rational sequence converges... to an irrational number.

---

Intuitively, this is possible because the denominators get larger and larger, and "in the end" the denominator becomes infinite.

Answer (score 1):

As $n\rightarrow\infty$ your expression can be written as $$F^n(x)=\frac{1}{1+F^n (x)}$$

or $$F^n(x)+\left (F^n(x)\right)^2=1$$ which approaches the golden ratio, but notice that this is just a limit. Just like $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$ is a limit of a rational sum.

Answer (score 0):

> But we see above that we will continue to get rational fractions however long we continue.

That's true, as long as "however long we continue" is a *finite* number of iterations. We can imagine iterating the function a finite number of times, even if that number is really large and it isn't physically possible to do the calculations that many times, and still getting a rational number.

However, we can't possibly imagine iterating infinitely many times and arriving at an answer. That process is impossible, even in theory.

Thus, this claim isn't entirely true:

> Continuing in this way to infinite number of times it turns out that we get √5-1/2.

We can't continue infinitely many times and get a result.

What we can say is that the more we continue (i.e., the "closer to infinity" we get in terms of number of iterations), the closer our answer gets to $\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}$. That means $\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}$ is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers. As the other answers have already pointed out, our definition of irrational numbers doesn't preclude them from being limits of sequences of rational numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If a function $f(x)$ is iterated in itself then it will converge to a point but this will happen if we assume infinite iterations which is just a concept and thats why we solve $f(x)=x$ which gives us expected result but that does not make result rational